# If I work as a freelancer, do I need a company to invoice my customer?

Tags: contractor, billing, singapore, malaysia

I am from Malaysia. Recently, I found a company in Singapore that wants to hire me as a freelancer. How should we do the payments? I have a bank account in Singapore and I am wondering if there will be any problem if they send the monthly payment there.

Moreover, if, say, I created a Payoneer or Payza account, and invoiced my client, do I need to have a company to create an invoice?

Comment: Both Payoneer and Payza allow you to sign up either as an individual or a company, so setting up a company is not required. I don't see why Singapore would care if you're a Malaysian company or a Malaysian individual, but I'm not an expert in either Singaporean or Malaysian law.

Comment: Singapore and Malaysia have a tax treaty so it probably doesn't matter all that much- they may wish to withhold Singapore employment taxes if it's not going out of country and being paid into an individual account. Suggest you consult a local accountant.